# Using same config files for multiple codeigniter projects

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure

I'm setting up a project where i wish to use the same codeigniter system + share some common models, libraries and even config files between the different websites.

I have put my system folder and a shrunk in application folder in docs/include/codeigniter and i define the path for the system folder in the index file of every website. I figure, that in order to use the models, libraries and config files from this application folder, i should use the add_package_path() function from https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html

But where can i put this call to make sure that it loads as early as possible? I would like to be able to even share the autoload.php config file, but if i call this method in the constructor of the index controller i will receive an error, because CI needs to use some of the config files before starting to load controllers.

Comment: If that's the case, make them one application & use folders + routes to manage it as if it was two applications. There's no point of writing two applications if you're going to re-use all the stuffs from  the first one.

Comment: @tereško: You are generally right and I would have chosen this solution too, but sometimes (as it happened to me) you just don't get to write the code from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution using `add_package_path()`, but this could work:

## Configuration

Firstly, check out `application/config/autoload.php` for `$autoload['config']`.

If it for some reason does not suit your purposes: The CodeIgniter config files are also just PHP files. So you can make your own `common_config.php` file and then just use `require '../some_common_folder/common_config.php';` in the configuration files of your CodeIgniter projects.

## Models

Again, see `application/config/autoload.php` for `$autoload['model']`.

You can also define your own `function __autoload($classname) {}` in the `index.php` file of each of your CodeIgniter projects, where you can load/require/include whatever you want.